# SQL - Totalizar suma realizada de tablas de bases de datos diferentes

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos bases de datos y en cada una dos tablas de las cuales necesito sumar un campo, pero unificado.

Hice el siguiente `query` pero me separa los resultados de cada tabla y necesito los dos:

```
Select sum(Cantidades) as Entregado 
From BD1..Facturas

Where Codigo ='00050'

Union All

Select sum(Cantidades) as Entregado 
From BD2..FacturasA

Where Codigo ='00050'
```

**Resultado**

Entregado

- 5773
- 90

Resultado esperado

> Entregado: 5863

Answer (score 4, accepted):

debes porner dentro de una tabla derivada de esta forma:

```
   SELECT
      SUM(t.Entregado)Entregado
   FROM
   (
      Select sum(Cantidades) as Entregado 
      From BD1..Facturas

      Where Codigo ='00050'

      Union All

      Select sum(Cantidades) as Entregado 
      From BD2..FacturasA

      Where Codigo ='00050'
   )t
```